# How to play a sound in C++?

Tags: c++, audio

I want to play a sound using C++. I'm not playing an audio file, but a certain voice. (Maybe functions like `play_sound(frequency, amplitude, time)`.).

I want it to be cross-platform.

Comment: C++ does not have that specific ability. You need to use a 3rd party library or direct calls to the OS. What OS are you using?

Comment: MacOS, but I want to cross-platform. @JohnnyMopp

Comment: Sorry, not a Mac programmer. Searching Google is probably your best option at this point since [_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ycao,

As far as I know, you will need some third party library.
Personally, I would use FMOD.
It's quite simple to use, well documented, you will find a lot code snippet to bootstart your project and it has a lot of interesting features.

[FMOD Website](https://www.fmod.com/)